# Automatically generate QR Code and create PDF file in PHP

Tags: pdf, generate

i want to create a dynamic PDF file. The file will be built by clicking the "download" button.

In this PDF it should be generate a QR code. This code should also be add to the PDF file.

Has anyone an idea which PHP libraries are best to use? And which generator for QR codes?

Thanks in advance!